# How to not rebuild the project without changes in the directory?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to write Makefile which would rebuild the file "./target/js/bundle.js" after changing any file in a directory "./ts" or its subdirectories. "make" should not rebuild "./target/js/bundle.js" without changing any file in a directory "./ts" or its subdirectories.

The structure of the project:

```
/ts - directory with typescript's sources
/ts/tsconfig.json - config for the tsc (TypeScript compiler), this filename is known by tsc
/target/js/bundle.js - target file
/Makefile
```

/ts/tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outFile": "../target/js/build.js"
    }
}
```

My Makefile:

```
target/js/bundle.js: ts/*
    cd ts && tsc
clean:
    rm -r target
```

Now "make" run "cd ts && tsc" every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in naming of files:

In `/ts/tsconfig.json` the name of the target file is `build.js`, but in `Makefile` the name of the file is `bundle.js`. So the GNU make is looking that `bundle.js` does not exist and rebuild project.

Answer (score 0):

This rule:

```
target/js/bundle.js: ts/*
        cd ts && tsc
```

says that if the file `target/js/bundle.js` does not exist, or it does exist but some file matching the glob pattern `ts/*` has a newer modification time, then re-run the recipe.

So, if you're seeing the recipe re-run every time then one of those two things is always true.

You can run `make -d` to have make generate a lot of information about how it's making its decision; that will tell you why it decides to rebuild the target.

I don't know how `tsc` works: are you sure that running `tsc` from the `ts` directory will understand that it needs to build the file `../target/js/bundle.js`?

Comment: Yes, I have got 'target/js/bundle.js' after run 'make'. And every run 'make' execute 'cd ts && tsc' (I do not change anything in 'ts/').

Comment: Then it must be that that file is not being updated.  Is the modification time on it changing?  As I said, run `make -d` and it will tell you why it decides to rebuild the target.

Comment: Thank you very much. `make -d` has said: `File 'target/js/bundle.js' does not exist`. Then I named file in tsconfig.json: `build.js, but in Makefile: `bundle.js`.